# Is there a project type for classic assembly + universal Apps

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to create a small Web-Service on my Raspberry Pi2, which uses the Project Types "Universal Windows".
The Problem is, I'd like to contact this Web-Service via an App running on my PC. Since this is using the LyncSDK, it has to be a Classic Windows App.

My problem: I'd like to have a shared Model-Assembly to assure I use the same Objects for the Serialization.
In this Assembly I'd need to use the Windows.UI.Color-Enum: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb189018.aspx

The closest Project-Type I found so far, was the "Class Library (Portable for iOS, Android and Windows), but I can't use the mentioned Enum.

Is there some Project, which bridges this Gap? The other Workarround I see so far is to save the RGB-Values.

Comment: If your enum is the only thing , just create your own and map it in both UI layer to Windows.UI.Color.

Comment: Uh, this is a huge Enum, you know? There are all Colors defined. One might think, since this Enum is avaliable in the Universal Windows- and in the Classic-Project Types, there has to be a bridge between them?

Comment: @MatthiasMüller Check its metadata and copy-paste it lol

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer that is what I 'm saying. And use regex to create dictionary that will map your enum on original enum in the part of your project that can reference that assembly. Or even cast to int and back.

Comment: Hm ok thanks, I created now my own Color-Class and on the Clients an Extension to map it from the Native one. My question was more general, not only about this exact enum. The answer could have been "Yes, use project type xx and you get everything yout want out of the box".